# can we install informatica server and client in one machine?

Tags: oracle11g, informatica

can we install informatica server and client in one machine?

I am facing issues with configuring the odbc for informatica. Can anyone please let me know how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could install the PowerCenter client on the same machine as the server.

To enable Oracle connectivity via ODBC you will need to install and configure the Oracle Instant Client (or equivalent). Once you have a connect string from your tnsnames.ora file you can configure an ODBC connection using the Data Sources (ODBC) configuration page (assuming you are using Windows).